# search a word from a text file in python

Tags: python, text

I have a text file containing words like: "ak", "bh", "cd", "dfg".
Now in Python how do I find the word `'df'` exist or not?

My code:

```
filename =raw_input("Enter the new Shop Name: ")
cs =open('shopname.txt','r')
for line in cs.readlines():
    if re.search(filename, line, re.I):
        print "Already Exists!!"
```

The text file is:
[Image of the txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2On6x.png).
Now if I put my input as `'df'`, it shows that the word exists. But I do not want to show that.
I want it to be specific and case sensitive.

Comment: please provide a sample line of your text file. and desired output for different examples to explain better your problem. thanks

Comment: `re.search(filename, line)` Just remove `re.I`.

Comment: just `"df" in line`, no need for regex for that, then

Comment: but it is showing that 'df' exists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each shop name is in separate line.

```
filename =raw_input("Enter the new Shop Name: ")

cs =open('shopname.txt','r')

for line in cs.readlines():
    if re.match(filename + '$', line, re.I):
        print "Already Exists!!"
```

`re.search` searches through out the line/word. Use match instead

Comment: it is showing some error. File "DATABASE.py", line 12, in <module>
    if re.match(filename, line, re.I).group(0) != '':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this. You can use `in` to search for that specific word:

```
filename =raw_input("Enter the new Shop Name: ")

cs = open('shopname.txt','r')

for line in cs.readlines():
    if 'df' in line:
        print "Already Exists!!"
```

I've also corrected your bug (might just be a copy-paste issue). You missed the colon at the end of the `if` condition.

More, if you're only looking for a sepparate `df` word, you might give [this regex a try](https://regex101.com/r/kWuFoO/2).

> \b Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a
>   word.

Note that the `re` module uses a naive definition of "word" as a "sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters", where "alphanumeric" depends on locale or unicode options.

More, it's recommended to use `with()` when you're dealing with files as it'll take care of some things for you (e.g: it'll automatically close the file for you)

```
with open('shopname.txt') as cs:  # this will close the file for you as well
    for line in cs:  # you don't need to use readlines here
        if re.search(r'\bdf\b', sentence):
            print('True')
```

Comment: the missing colon bug is from my edit (removing html tags went wrong)

Comment: i think he doesn't want the script to return that df exists if he has dfg instead, but without knowing how his "words" are separated in the file we can't do much can we ?

Comment: Agree with @RayhaneMama

Comment: I've already updated my solution to cover that case as well (supposing that a word is delimited by spaces, ofc)

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect..you should have shop name in each new line

```
filename =raw_input("Enter the new Shop Name: ")
check =open('shopname.txt','r')
file=filename+"\n"   #CODE MODIFIED HERE
for line in check.readlines():
    if line.find(file)>=0:         #CODE ALSO MODIFIED HERE
        print "Already Exists!!"
    else:
        print ""
```

Comment: It is also not working. If I give the input 'df' as filename ,I want the program will not return anything because 'df' is not present in the text file only 'dfg' is present. But here it is returning 'Already exists!!'.

Comment: Sorry for above comments dude......   this modified code satisfy you criteria   try this now.....#CODE MODIFIED